# Flutter: How show a simple SpriteWidget from a simple Spritesheet

Tags: flutter

dependencies:
spritewidget: ^2.0.1

Can anyone provide an example of how to display a simple sprite sheet animation with Flutter SpriteWidget? I've been reading the docs and trying to get the sprite sheet animation to show but with no success. i don' t know if I'm not following it correctly, but I've been trying for hours and I feel the example provide on the package page are to complexed. I just want to display the bottom sprite sheet rendered as animation widget. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: and do you have to use `spritewidget` package?

Comment: Well not necessarily, is it possible to achieve this with any other package? I know there is flame but flame uses components, not widgets.